# saving image into access db in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am not able to save an image from a form1's picbox.image into my access DataBase .
How can i Save the image into access db and which datatype do i need to use for saving an image into accessdb

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access you need to use the OLE Object data type.

Here's some C# code to save the image into the database. Sorry it isn't VB.Net.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/AccessBlob.aspx

Comment: You know it is almost never a good idea to save images to Access, yesno?

Comment: Very much agree, Remou. I guess I was just trying to give the OP what he wants, not what I think he needs.

Comment: I highly recommend doing both, since to me, that makes a much higher quality answer.

Comment: Second like is down - I got a 404